# results variable is not properly exporting to CSV

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

```
$results = foreach ($domain in $domains) {
    Resolve-DnsName -Name $domain -Type ALL -Server $dns_server  
}  
$results | Select-Object -Property Name, IP4Address, QueryType, NameHost, NameExchange, Strings, PrimaryServer, NameAdministrator, SerialNumber | 
Export-Csv -path $save_path -NoTypeInformation
```

The CSV output colunm shows [image: excel output]

The raw output shows this [image]

Comment: Since `Strings` appears to be an array, you will need to create a single string by joining together its elements. You can try `Select Strings` --> `Select @{n='Strings';e={$_.Strings -join ';'}}`.

Comment: Or use json instead.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Json example.  The array will be preserved when converting it back to an object.

```
[pscustomobject]@{name='Joe';strings='one','two','three'} | convertto-json

{
    "name":  "Joe",
    "strings":  [
                    "one",
                    "two",
                    "three"
                ]
}
```